# Twig Inheritance: get raw resulting template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm developing Symfony2 + Twig project. I need to get raw not interpeted template (variables shouldn't be replaced) string in Symfony2 Controller after merging with its parent template.

For example:
parent.html.twig

```
{% block title %}
    Parent Content
{%  endblock %}
```

child.html.twig
    {% extends "parent.html.twig" %}

```
{% block title %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ CHILD_CONTENT }}
{% endblock %}
```

Desirable result is a string:

```
Parent Content
{{ CHILD_CONTENT }}
```

I've heard about [source](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/source.html) function in 1.15 version, but it doesn't handle inheritance.

Is there any way to get around?

Comment: It's strange, try to change "CHILD_CONTENT" per "child_content" or another name, it may be a twig problem.

Comment: Please read carefully my problem.

Answer (score 1):

already tried "verbatim"? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html

Your code should look like this:

```
{% block title %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% verbatim %}
        {{ CHILD_CONTENT }}
    {% endverbatim %}
{% endblock %}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: tvelykyy, plese specify your question. My provided code exactly delivers the output as you mentioned with "Desirable result is a string". What do you mean by "is a different thing"

Comment: Yes, the output it correct. But I should change an input (source of my templates). I can do this, because in one Controller I should render my templates interpreted and in another Controller uninterpreted. Does it make sense for you?